# cannot use an AJAX response as a filename (not content)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am sending a `$.post` request to a servlet, sending some data, which needs to be saved in a file. the servlet save the data then sends back the **path** to the file. I am trying to navigate to that path held by the `response` within the callback of the method but here's what's going on:

```
function saveData(){
    var path;

    $.post("SaveFileServlet", {data : JSON.stringify(jsonPieces)}, function(response) {
        path = response; // setting the path like this does NOT WORK - nothing happens           
        //path="storing/csv_uploads/test.csv"; // setting the path like this WORKS        

        alert (path); // shows: storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv - e.g. WHAT IT SHOULD

        $("body").append("<iframe src='" + path + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");       
    });        
}
```

How to make it work and why isn't it working?
thanks.

**even newer edit**

GOT IT!!!!!... it's the servlet: it's probably not creating the file : the real path is not `filename.csv` but a `System.currentTimeMillis()+".csv"` and then I write it to the server. but I am only sending the response after I'm creating the file (or am I?)...

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String filename = "storing/csv_uploads/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".csv";
    //String filename = "storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv"; //this works since it was previously there
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<PieceFeeder>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<PieceFeeder> pieceFeeders = new Gson().fromJson(request.getParameter("data"), type);            

        DataManager dm = new DataManager();
        if (dm.exportPieces(pieceFeeders, filename)) {
            System.out.println("in SaveFileServlet: after exportPieces");
            File f = new File(filename);
            while (!f.exists()) {
                //waiting...I NEVER GET IN HERE
                System.out.println("in SaveFileServlet: waiting for file to exist");
            }
            out.write(filename);
        } else {
            out.write("error at creating file");
        }
    }...
}
```

and the `DataManager.exportPieces`:

```
public void exportPieces(ArrayList<PieceFeeder> pieceFeeders, String filename) {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

        //write first line without "\n"
        if (pieceFeeders.size() > 0) {
            PieceFeeder pf = pieceFeeders.get(0);
            Piece p = pf.getPiece();
            bufferedWriter.write(p.getDescription() + ","
                    + pf.getStock() + ","
                    + p.getLength() + ","
                    + p.getWidth() + ","
                    + p.getLengthEdges() + ","
                    + p.getWidthEdges());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < pieceFeeders.size(); i++) {
            PieceFeeder pf = pieceFeeders.get(i);
            Piece p = pf.getPiece();
            bufferedWriter.write("\n" + p.getDescription() + ","
                    + pf.getStock() + ","
                    + p.getLength() + ","
                    + p.getWidth() + ","
                    + p.getLengthEdges() + ","
                    + p.getWidthEdges());
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    } finally {
        //Close the BufferedWriter
        try {
            if (bufferedWriter != null) {
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                System.out.println("in exportPieces: finally"); 
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I always get

`"in exportPieces: finally"`

`"in SaveFileServlet: after exportPieces"`

and the `"in SaveFileServlet: waiting for file to exist"` never gets called 
so the file exists before the response is sent

but if I send an old file *one that has not just been created), it works

**newer edit**

just to make it clear: if I do:

- `window.location = path`
- `$("body").append("<iframe src='" + path + "' ></iframe>");` removed the `display:none`
  it give a `404 error`: `The requested resource () is not available.` but the header shows I'm trying to access : `http://localhost:8080/optimizerwithservlet/storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv` so it's there

**EDIT**

as users sugeested I installed Firebug, and here's what I got :

```
<iframe style="display: none;" src="storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv">
```

meaning it works ! but why isn't it displayed...?

**older edit:**

in case this might matter, though I doubt it : here is the relevant piece of code from the servlet:

```
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String filename = "storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv";
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(filename);
```

Comment: before `path = response` if you `alert(response)` do you get the expected results?

Comment: yes... and you can see that I first `alert(path=response)` and then try to use it.. and it prints perfectly...

Comment: What happens if you set the source of the iframe to be the complete path?

Comment: If you're using Google Chrome, type ctrl + shift + J and see if javascript is outputting any errors. If it does, tell us which error it is.

Comment: @freon : using Firefox but will install chrome just to make this check and come back..

Comment: @Barry Chapman : it works ... as you can see the second line of code within the `$.post`... the commented one...

Comment: @claudiaalexa Firefox works too. Same keys.

Comment: have you told us what the contents of 'path' are when you alert it inside the response?

Comment: @BarryChapman She did. `alert (path); // shows: storing/csv_uploads/filename.csv`

Comment: i have a sneaking suspicion that this is a relative path issue

Comment: @freon did that Ctrl-Shift-J and i only get a couple of warnings regarding some css... so I guess the answer is no.. no errors

Comment: @Barry Chapman : I doubt it, since you can see I tried writing the path manually and it works, but if I try to pass the response which holds the string ... well that's a different story...

Comment: There's got to be something else going on here...it all looks correct

Comment: see the edit : firebug shows I'm getting the right path.. but no download!! aaaahh!!

Comment: It's not an ajax / jQuery question anymore. You should change the tags in order to bring people who can help you here.

Answer (score 3):

`$.post` is asynchronous.  You are trying to alert the value before it exists, that is all.

From [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the
>   operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not
>   guaranteed. The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating
>   that code execution can continue after the request is made. Setting
>   this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous)
>   is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become
>   unresponsive.

Comment: nevermind.. i didnt see that second one!

Comment: this explains the "undefined" and I realised that so I should remove that line of code, for it's misleading. my real problem is what happens inside the `$.post`: why can't I set the response as the filename? since it obviously exists, because the alert prints it just fine.

Comment: @BarryChapman I didn't see your first comment so I'm gonna assume I should be offended for about a second, and then not be

Comment: Actually it's not true. The alert is inside the callback, wich is executed only AFTER the call is done.

Comment: @freon He edited his question.  He had one outside the callback and one inside

Comment: sorry guys for the misleading as I said...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You may need to specify the dataType as "text" to ensure a string comes back.

In the callback, assuming `response` is a string, you can simply do:

```
window.location = response;
```

That will redirect the browser to the path indicated by the response, assuming it is an absolute url or root-relative (i.e., begins with /).

Comment: He wants to set the source of an `<iframe/>`

Comment: The OP says "I am trying to navigate to that path held by the response within the callback of the method..." Nothing specifically about an `iframe`, except in the code.

Comment: doesn't work.. tried that way too, but it's not because of that. the thing with the `iframe` is just because I don't want to leave the page

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the browser show it's loading?

Comment: @Mike McCaughan : nope, no error no movement, nothing ...

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the browser's JavaScript debugger at that point? Because when I type `window.location = ""` at the console, it at least does a refresh, so maybe it's not even getting to that line.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know anything about debugging (I just did my first CTRL-SHIFT-J now.. as another user suggested) buuuut.. if it helps with anything, I did place **another alert after that line** and it shows just fine

Answer (score 0):

Claudia:

Are you absolutely certain that your response you are getting from your servlet is a simple string with your path? There isn't any whitespace or anything like that around it? If uncertain, try setting your `dataType` to `text`.

My suggestion to you, is to put an `<iframe>` in your page with the `src` attribute set to your file download path. Make sure that you are even able to access the file. This will at least rule out if it is a relative path issue or not.

Instead of using `alert()`, use `console.log()` - as the `console.log()` will preserve the data structure and let you view it properly.

**EDIT**

```js
function saveData(){
    var path;

    $.post("SaveFileServlet", {dataType: 'text', data : JSON.stringify(jsonPieces)}, function(response) {
        path = response; // setting the path like this does NOT WORK - nothing happens           

        console.log (path); 

        $("body").append("<iframe src='" + path + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");       
    });        
}
```

Comment: as answered above, tried writing the path manually , and it works, and there are no whitespaces in the response from servlet :) ((which is set to be text/plain, if that helps)

Comment: Try that piece of code. See if that works for you

Comment: Did you try the code i placed in the edit?

Comment: see the new edit... the firebug thing... and did as you said also: it prints just right... so it's not that

Comment: Why isn't it displayed? It wont be because you have `display: none;` in there

Comment: aaaawww... well meanwhile thanks for the console.log idea (learned something new...so this was not a waste after all)

Comment: yes I see it ( the path is right) . There's just no download!

Comment: GOT IT!!!!!... it's the servlet: it's probably not creating the file : the real path is not `filename.csv` but a `System.currentTimeMillis()+".csv"` and then I write it to the server. I guess it's not done creating it..?? but I am only sending the response after I'm creating the file (or am I)...

Comment: you need to reassess your logic to make sure you only send the response to the browser when the file has been generated

Comment: true that.. I thought I did... Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score -1):

The problem is order of execution.  As climbage pointed out, ajax calls are asynchronous, so the browser is continuing to do stuff as it waits for the result.

At it's most basic:

```
function doSomething() {
    $.post("SaveFileServlet", {data : JSON.stringify(jsonPieces)}, function(response) {
      alert('post done');
    }
    alert('doSomething done');
}
```

Almost 100% of the time, the first alert that you will get will be the 'doSomething done' not 'post done'.

This is because JavaScript is not waiting for the ajax call to complete to keep on going to the next step.

Comment: already mentioned that's not the issue.. and removed that second alert for it's irrelevant here and misleading..

Comment: So you voted me down because I answered your original question?  Thanks, but I won't be helping you out any more.

Comment: I didn't vote you down :) don't have enough rights on SO to make votes ... and that was not my original question.. as you can see in the title.